# Restringir 'type' do argumento de um método em Python

Tags: python, funções, classes

Preciso definir uma classe em Python, que receberá uma série de parâmetros. Eu gostaria de fazer com que os métodos recebessem argumentos de um determinado tipo. Um exemplo do código:

```
class Teste():
    def __init__(self, arg1: tuple = (8,6)):
        self.arg1=arg1


    def setArg(self,arg1):
        self.arg1=arg1
```

Então, assim que eu chamasse o construtor da classe, ou o método `.setArg()`, eles só aceitem, por exemplo, tuplas de tamanho 2 como argumento (ou outros casos como inteiro ou string).

Nesse código, caso eu colocasse um argumento inteiro, por exemplo, `t = Teste(arg1 = 10)` ou `t.setArg(10)`, ele retornaria um erro dizendo que o argumento deve ser uma tupla.

Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso sem precisar criar um código dentro de cada método para verificar o tipo e, caso a restrição de tipo não seja respeitada, levantar uma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Veja a resposta aceita na pergunta considerada duplicada. Se tiver duvidas mais específicas depois, pode criar outra pergunta - mas adianto um comentário que não escrevi na resposta a pergunta linkada acima:

Comment: Python, sendo uma linguagem dinâmica, _não_ tem o conceito de verificação implícita de argumentos. Tudo que é recebido numa função é um "objeto Python". O que existe hoje em dia é um mecanismo opcional de checagem estática de argumentos, que pode ser executado antes da execução do programa - (isso é, num momento equivalente ao "build" do projeto de linguagens que precisam de um passo explícito de compilação).  Se quiser fazer isso, siga as instruções em algum tutorial de uso do "MyPy" (o checador de tipagem meio "oficial" )

Comment: Eu vi a resposta da outra pergunta, mas esqueci de remover a minha kkkkk. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Pode deixar essa pergunta aí - por que quando alguém for buscar, pode fazer uma busca diferente que caia aqui primeiro. Pra mim, o importante é ficar claro isso: Python não faz de forma automática, e isso é uma opção de design da linguagem do 'momento zero' - assim como acontece com Javascript.

Comment: O que não fica claro até se entender muito é que tentativas de se ativar restrições desse tipo vão implicar em checagens em tempo de execução, que tem um custo em performance - enquanto que não fazer uma checagem - por exemplo, a pessoa mana uma string onde era uma tupla por engano - vai dar um erro do mesmo jeito - só quando o programa estiver rodando. Pra descobrir possiveis pontos onde parametros incorretos são passados _antes_ do programa rodar, só com a checagem estática do mypy.